# Docker REST API Golang

Tags: database, docker, rest, routes, controller

Hey guys i'm a new to docker, and i don't understand how to install my Golang application that have a routes, controller, and database config to Docker,after I searched on the internet, all I found was how to run 1 main.go file only, do i need to make route image, controller image, and database image to make my application run on docker?? or just make main.go image in docker to access all ?? sorry for my bad grammar.. i hope you guys understand what i'm talking about appriciate your help

Here my Main.go code

```
package main
import (
    "dikota/config"
    "dikota/models"
    "dikota/routes"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
)
var err error

func main() {
    config.DB, err = gorm.Open("mysql", config.DbURL(config.BuildDBConfig()))

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Status:", err)
    }
    //config.DB
    defer config.DB.Close()
    config.DB.AutoMigrate(&models.Konten{})
    config.DB.AutoMigrate(&models.User{})
    r := routes.SetupRouter()
    //running
    r.Run()
}
}
```

Here my routes code

```
    package routes

import (
    "dikota/controllers"
    "time"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    cors "github.com/itsjamie/gin-cors"
)

//SetupRouter Function
func SetupRouter() *gin.Engine {
    router := gin.Default()

    // Apply the middleware to the router (works with groups too)
    router.Use(cors.Middleware(cors.Config{
        Origins:         "*",
        Methods:         "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE,OPTIONS",
        RequestHeaders:  "Origin, Authorization, Content-Type",
        ExposedHeaders:  "",
        MaxAge:          50 * time.Second,
        Credentials:     true,
        ValidateHeaders: false,
    }))
    // grp1 := r.Group("/user-api")
    // {
    //  grp1.GET("user", controllers.GetUsers)
    //  grp1.POST("user", controllers.CreateUser)
    //  grp1.GET("user/:id", controllers.GetUserByID)
    //  grp1.PUT("user/:id", controllers.UpdateUser)
    //  grp1.DELETE("user/:id", controllers.DeleteUser)
    // }

    grp1 := router.Group("/konten-api")
    {
        grp1.GET("konten", controllers.GetKontens)
        grp1.POST("createkonten", controllers.CreateKonten)
        // grp1.GET("konten/:id", controllers.GetKontenByID)
        // grp1.PUT("konten/:id", controllers.UpdateKonten)
        // grp1.DELETE("konten/:id", controllers.DeleteKonten)
    }
    return router
}
```

Here my database config code

```
package config

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
)

//DB variable
var DB *gorm.DB

//DBConfig struct
type DBConfig struct {
    Host     string
    Port     int
    User     string
    DBName   string
    Password string
}

//BuildDBConfig function
func BuildDBConfig() *DBConfig {
    dbConfig := DBConfig{
        Host:     "localhost",
        Port:     3306,
        User:     "root",
        Password: "dikota123",
        DBName:   "DIKOTA",
    }
    return &dbConfig
}

//DbURL function
func DbURL(dbConfig *DBConfig) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf(
        "%s:%s@tcp(%s:%d)/%s?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local",
        dbConfig.User,
        dbConfig.Password,
        dbConfig.Host,
        dbConfig.Port,
        dbConfig.DBName,
    )
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried on the Docker side?  What problems are you encountering?  The actual Go code is probably a little less interesting (though the hard-coded database configuration will be wrong in Docker); you should be able to build a single binary and package that in an image.

Comment: i have tried installing mysql and phpmyadmin on docker, and i want to connect my golang to my docker, the problem is GOROOT or GOPATH always said my routes, controller, models, is not found.. because i have called it on my main.go, but i dont know how to copy my other file to docker